# Optimising code using List in c#

Tags: c#

I have list of string may contain a large number of records, the problem is I have to check each record and collect the exception thrown for individual records.I need to optimize this logic.Below is the snippet of the code which I have tried.

```
private void testSearchTerms(List<string> searchTerms,List<string> failures,SearchDTSearch searchDTSearch,string index,int skipRecordsCount)
{
    if (searchTerms.Any())
    {
        try
        {
            using (SearchResults searchResults = searchDTSearch.Execute(index, searchTerms, null))
            {
                ;//do nothing, we don't care about the results, just the fact that there was an error or not
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if ((ex.Message != null) && (ex.Message.Contains("Operation failed: open (could not open directory)")))
            {
                LogManager.Warning("Attempt to test search term failed due to index access problem.  Path of index used to test: '" + index + "'", ex);
            }
            else
            {
                //collect individual search terms with error
                foreach (var searchTerm in searchTerms)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (SearchResults searchResults = searchDTSearch.Execute(index, searchTerm, null))
                        {
                            ;//do nothing, we don't care about the results, just the fact that there was an error or not
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        failures.Add(searchTerm);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            var dividedSearchTerms = searchTerms.Skip(skipRecordsCount).Take((searchTerms.Count/2)).ToList();
            skipRecordsCount += dividedSearchTerms.Count();
            this.testSearchTerms(dividedSearchTerms, failures, searchDTSearch, index, skipRecordsCount);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Excute() can't be changed it takes a List as well as string

PSS: Can't use threading here

Comment: Are errors *stable* ones (i.e. if I repeat the same query I'll get the same error)? If they are, can we cache erroneous indexes? When search fails we store the index as erroneous?

Comment: could you not do forech loop which contains a try-catch then capture both the value and exception in the event one triggers and add that to a list? it should allow you to exectute on each value without stopping on the first exception

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I have to collect errorneous records whatever the error be can't show the Index, its a business requirement.

Comment: @Takarii  using Execute on single term is more time consuming so I am checking a batch and If batch contains error the collect the Individual record having an error

Comment: catching error for each execute will always took time cause system will collect error details first then handover it to exception - why don't you find other way of testing without trial execution & waiting for exception. what is HAPANING inside execute. or you can use linq where and pass function to execute for each element but this will only cut down lil time taken by for

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail what sort of checks you want to perform, with which data? If execute is your heavy process, then perhaps the logic you need to employ is to validate the list and only run execute on items certain to pass. That way you get split the bad data from the good data

Comment: @Takarii Here Execute is the one which going to tell whether the data is good or bad so can't filter out list before hand

Comment: I recommend you post the execute method to give a better picture of what is going on

Comment: @Takarii Execute is a third party method and I don't have the definition. The requirement here is to optimize this logic as much as possible, what I know is the Overload of execute which takes List is much faster than the one which takes single record

Comment: Knowing what that method does is likely key to suggesting improvements here. For all you/we know, it could be looping over something several hundred times without any real reason(highly unlikely, but just an illustration). I would refer you to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance on questions such as this - we need to see enough to replicate the "issue"

Comment: @Takarii as I aready said that Execute is a third party method and I don't have definition of it. But, I can tell you what it does - it takes a search term search them on a document and if somehow user has entered a searchterm with wrong wild cards it throws an error

Comment: @AkshayChoudhary What is `index` for in `Execute`, does it just tell `Execute` where to start in the list?

Comment: Did you already analyze the code with a profiler in order to determine the optimization potential? Also, can you please explain the purpose of your `finally` section?

Comment: if bulk execution is working faster then you can do one thing cut your execution batch in smaller pieces and execute bulk execute this will cut your time - ex if your batch is 1000 cut it to 50/50 execute 50 at once if error you only have to execute 50 idividual statemens to check error not all 1000 & for those 50 who clear test are ok to go -- check if this helps

Comment: ok, let me try a different approach at explaining what i mean. You are asking with help optimising, but can't provide all the information as you are limited. If you don't have access to all the information, how can you possibly optimise?

Comment: @Takarii I need to optimise the amount of code which I have written considering that the third party method will always take time.

Comment: amount of code or time it takes to execute ?

Comment: @JackGajanan  time it takes to execute

Comment: have you tried the method i suggest ?